# Is "elect someone to x" idiomatic?

Tags: idiomatic-language

I looked on Google and there's rarely anyone ever using the expression elect someone to x, as in choose someone to do something, so I was wondering if it was grammatical in any way.

For example:

> They elected him to pilot the aircraft, which was in free fall,
>   because he had the most experience within our group.

Comment: They picked or selected him. elect, not here.

Comment: Why would elect be wrong though? If they have a vote, shouldn't it be elect?

Comment: When an airplane is falling, there's no voting. Elect is for elections. Elections take time....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is a little silly, because people are unlikely to vote in that situation. *Elect*, in that sort of context, suggests that they were chosen through a vote.

However, the general point of electing people to do something is fine. [Google Ngram Viewer shows a lot of "elected him to" phrases](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=elected%20him%20to%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Celected%20him%20to%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Belected%20him%20to%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belected%20him%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belected%20him%20to%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belected%20him%20to%20Congress%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belected%20him%20to%20represent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belected%20him%20to%20office%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belected%20him%20to%20membership%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belected%20him%20to%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belected%20him%20to%20fill%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belected%20him%20to%20his%3B%2Cc0), and some of them have verbs as the next word. Of course, if it's electing someone to do a job, to fill a position, [you see "*elected him as*" a lot, too](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=elected%20him%20to%20*%2Celected%20him%20as%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Celected%20him%20to%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Belected%20him%20to%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belected%20him%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belected%20him%20to%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belected%20him%20to%20Congress%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belected%20him%20to%20represent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belected%20him%20to%20office%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belected%20him%20to%20membership%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belected%20him%20to%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belected%20him%20to%20fill%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belected%20him%20to%20his%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Celected%20him%20as%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Belected%20him%20as%20their%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belected%20him%20as%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belected%20him%20as%20its%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belected%20him%20as%20one%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belected%20him%20as%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belected%20him%20as%20successor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belected%20him%20as%20an%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belected%20him%20as%20her%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belected%20him%20as%20President%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belected%20him%20as%20president%3B%2Cc0). It's the fact of when people would vote that does a lot to determine what verb you might see after "elected him to".

Now, *elect* can be a formal way to say *choose*, but **not** in order to say "choose to do a job" unless that choice was by voting. For example, "I elected to stay home that day" means I chose to stay at home that day, and it's a bit formal and stilted but perfectly normal. But "I elect you to do this job" doesn't make sense unless you're suggesting you did it by voting.